# Shader building in Haskell

Tags: opengl, haskell, shader, dsl

I'm making a rendering engine in Haskell, and am tackling the way I use shaders based off simple case statements and Maybe data types.

I've got 4 different types of shaders at the moment:

- Simple Shader,
- Light Shader (Phong),
- Texture Shader,
- Light + Texture Shader

At the moment, I've got separate shader files for each of them, but I'd like to introduce the other shading models. There are at least 3 different shading models, and I've not even done colour.

So in total there are 4(Flat, Gourad, Phong, no lighting)*2(Texture on/off)*2(Colour on/off) = 16 possibilities and I don't want to have to have separate shader files for each of them. It just doesn't seem like a good model to have.

So I'd like to build it up using a DSL. This one seems pretty good: https://github.com/fiendfan1/Haskell-GLSL-eDSL

Does anyone have any tips on how I might do that? I'd like to make it easy to add more possibilities as well, since I'll effectively have to at least double it each time I add something. It gets incredibly cumbersome.

So here's how I do it at the moment:

```
p <- case (sProgram state) of
        (Just sp) -> return sp
        Nothing -> case (lighting state) of 
            (Just _) -> case (texture state) of
                (Just _) -> ltShader state
                Nothing -> lShader state
            Nothing -> case (texture state) of
                (Just _) -> tShader state
                Nothing -> sShader state
```

Each shader function sets up the uniform/attribute variables and stuff. Thank you in advance for helping me!

Comment: Your `p <-` expression can be more concisely expressed with the `Applicative` and `Alternative` instances of `Maybe`. As to the dsl; My first idea would be to build up a low level dsl for writing shaders and then just combine the higher level effects with premade parts; But I'm not sure what your goal here is.

Comment: Oh, really? Do you mind expanding a bit more on that. I didn't think I could make it more compact! 

Well, as for the DSL, the library I've mentioned seems to have a decent API for it, so I'd like to know what's the best way of combining each part. The goal is to be able to have flags determine the output shader in as concise manner as possible. This goes for vertex attributes and uniform variables as well.

Comment: It's not quite clear what your question is. Are you trying to build a shader eDSL? Are you trying to integrate the existing one into your engine? Also, the code you posted can be made cleaner by pattern matching on `(lighting state, texture state)`

Comment: I'd like to integrate the one mentioned in my original post in to my engine. You mean, assign them variables prior to the case statement?